# grep in bash script not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, grep

If I run

```
grep -i "echo" *
```

I get the results I want, but if I try the following simple bash script

```
#search.sh
grep -i "$1" *
echo "####--DONE--####"
```

and I run it with `sh -x search.sh "echo"` I get the following error output:

```
' grep -i echo '*
: No such file or directory
' echo '####--DONE--####
####--DONE--####
```

How come? I'm on CentOS

Comment: How does `echo ####--DONE--####` end up outputting `####--FINE--####`?   I think there's something you're not showing here.

Comment: If you run `bash -x ...` instead of `sh -x ...`, does it work?

Comment: Did you try adding the line `#!/bin/bash` at the very top of your script and then running the script as `./search.sh "echo"`?

Comment: are you really get the single-quotes at the front of lines 1 and 3 on your ouput? Good luck.

Comment: Please make sure to show us the **exact** script and output. My guess is you're running the script from an empty directory and therefore `*` gives `No such file or directory`.

Comment: @RobWouters: Plausible, but the exact error message would be `grep: *: No such file or directory`, not what the OP showed.  Also, `sh -x` on CentOS prefixes printed commands with `+`, not `'`.  I'm reasonably sure the OP isn't showing us the actual script *or* the actual output.

Comment: Oh, and the OP is running the script from the current directory; it can't be empty, `search.sh` is there.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I know, hence my first sentence. He didn't copy the output exactly as indicated by the edit he made, which is kind of important.

Comment: Yes I realized that too, still I think it's likely he ran it from a different directory.

Comment: Using the bash shebang anche calling it via ./search.sh solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: Can @JaypalSingh post his comment as an answer and you'll accept it? This Q keeps showing up as an unanswered. OR is it possible for the O.P. to close (or delete) the question?

Comment: Thanks @shellter .. I have added my comment as an answer.

Comment: That's odd, I don't see why that would fix the problem.  Without the `#!`, the system will use `#!/bin/sh` to execute the script.  Using `/bin/sh` vs. `/bin/bash` might make some difference, but not for anything I see here.  If you'll copy-and-paste the *exact* contents of the script, and the *exact* output, this question might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the **sha-bang** line at the top of your script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and after making it executable, run the script using

```
./search.sh "echo"
```

Answer (score 0):

The "sh -x" should print the files that '*' matches. It looks like it's not matching any files. Are you maybe running it in a directory with no readable files?